# CheckedListBox updates checkedItems very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am using a CheckedListBox in my C# software. The software checks and unchecks items as well as the user by the graphical interface. I added a button to uncheck all items. When the user presses a button, the software should uncheck all items. Sometimes, when I uncheck the items by software after the button click, some items still appear in the checked items property of the listbox. Is it possible that the CheckedListBox needs some time to update the CheckedItems property? Or is something wrong with my Invoke-Usage?

I found out, that when I set a breakpoint in between the unchecking and the reading of the checked item, the checked items are updated properly.

```
//---------------------------------------------
// function to get the checked items
//---------------------------------------------
public List<object> getCheckedItems() {
    var returnedItems = new List<object>();
    var checkedItems = checkedListBox.CheckedItems;
    var iterator = checkedItems.GetEnumerator();
    while ( iterator.MoveNext() )
        returnedItems.Add( iterator.Current );

    return returnedItems;
} 

//---------------------------------------------
// function to uncheck an item
//---------------------------------------------
public void uncheckItem( object item ) {
    if ( containsItem( item ) ) {
        int index = checkedListBox.Items.IndexOf( item );
        if ( checkedListBox.InvokeRequired ) {
            var uncheckInvoker = 
                new MethodInvoker( () => checkedListBox.SetItemChecked( index, false ) );
            checkedListBox.BeginInvoke( uncheckInvoker );
        }
        else
            checkedListBox.SetItemChecked( index, false );

        // the following two line are added for debugging
        var items = checkedListBox.CheckedItems; // breakpoint here
        Console.WriteLine( "number of checked items = " + items.Count );
    }
    else 
        throw new ArgumentException( "Item " + item + " is not available" );
}

//---------------------------------------------
//client code
//---------------------------------------------
var checkedItems = subTestListBox.getCheckedItems();
foreach ( var checkedItem in checkedItems )
    subTestListBox.uncheckItem( checkedItem );
```

I expect that the checkedItems property is updated right after I called the `SetItemChecked( int, bool )` function.

Comment: Does `BeginInvoke` ever get hit if you place a breakpoint there (does your code contain multiple threads)? Furthermore, `BeginInvoke` doesn't wait for the call to complete, use `Invoke` if you want to wait for the listitem to actually be unchecked before running the next statement.

Comment: @Fixation Yes, my code does contain multiple threads and it gets it. It seems that using `Invoke` and not `BeginInvoke` solved the problem. I will provide an answer and mark it as soon as I have fully tested it. Thank you

Comment: Since you dont need to check the check state (becuase you are checking/unchecking ALL of them), you would probably also get better performance with a simple for loop that toggles the state of all items rather than query with an enumerator.  Also, one function to check the need for invoke rather than the check for each item would speed things up.

Comment: Or loop the `CheckedIndices` collection and set the corresponding Item index to non-checked: `foreach (int i in checkedListBox.CheckedIndices) { checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, false); }`. Your procedure is over the top complicated. You could also `BeginInvoke` a delegate method which runs in the UI thread and does it all.

Comment: They do get updated immediately, but there is no guarantee that you can actually see that.  The control has to repaint itself, when the UI thread is busy with "other software" then that can take a while.  BeginInvoke() just makes it worse, it isn't very fast and you can easily firehose the UI thread with too many repaints when it is called by a worker thread.  The proper way to use a thread is to only retrieve the data.  Update UI after it is done, like in the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event.  So there's just one repaint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplify?

```
private void UncheckAll(CheckedListBox clb)
{
    if (clb.InvokeRequired)
    {
        clb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            UncheckAll(clb);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < clb.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clb.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                clb.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fot this tip. Eliminates some redundant code